# I'm transforming my jsx file using babelify but shows pure html

Tags: javascript, express, reactjs, browserify, babeljs

I'm using browserify and babelify to transform my jsx files to js but when I start my express server nothing shows up, in the source tab in chrome dev tools I see that my bundle.js is html code. The thing is bundle.js should be my transformed jsx.

This is what I see in bundle.js in dev tools:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>SMS</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1>Hello!</h1>
        <div id="app"></div>
    </body>
    <script src="../dist/bundle.js"></script>
</html>
```

**server.js**

```
var express = require('express');

var app = new express();

app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);

app.get('*', function(req, res) {
    res.render('index.ejs');
});

app.use(express.static(__dirname + 'dist'));

var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(port, function() {
    console.log('Listening to port:', port)
});
```

**gulpfile.js**

```
gulp.task('build', function() {
    return (browserify({
        entries: './app/components/Main.jsx',
        debug: true
    }))
    .transform(babelify, {presets: ['es2015', 'react']})
    .bundle()
    .pipe(source('bundle.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'));
});

gulp.task('serve', function() {
    nodemon({
        script: 'server.js',
        ext: 'js jsx'
    }).on('restart', function() {
        console.log('Restarted app');
    })
});

gulp.task('default', ['build', 'serve']);
```

What am I doing wrong??

Comment: no errors in the console? are you sure path to bundle is not getting 404?

Comment: The only error it gives me is the unexpected token < (because it shows html tag but is a js file). No matter what path I give, it will show the bundle.js file with html

Comment: Oh that error is very important.. it means your babelify is not hooked up properly. `<` is not a legal javascript character, so it throws on the first jsx tag

Comment: But what am I doing wrong tho? I checked so many examples on how to do it. My bundle.js is generating valid js code, so idk what's wrong

Comment: I think you may be setting the wrong path in your html? I don't think html script paths can use `..` `<script src="../dist/bundle.js"></script>`

Comment: My problem was in my server.js, in my app.use I just had to change 'dist' to '/dist'